# Unexpected characters at end of line

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, arm, keil

I Writing a code that loops 1000 times in assembly language, although I keep getting these errors:

```
main.s(48): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
main.s(53): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
main.s(55): error: A1163E: Unknown opcode endloop , expecting opcode or Macro
".\SimpleProject.axf" - 3 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
```

Here is an Example of my code:

```
MOV R0, #1, i = 1;
startloop   
    cmp R0, #1000
    BGT endloop
        ADD R1, R1, R0
        ADD R0, R0, #1, i++;
        B startloop
endloop
```

line (48) refers to:

```
MOV R0, #1, i = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the erroneous line to:

```
MOV R0, #1
```

Clearly `i = 1;` was supposed to be a comment, but you accidentally typed a comma instead of whatever comment character is supported by your assembler.  Read the documentation of your assembler to learn comment syntax.

Comment: ARM assembly normally uses `@` as the comment character.  At least in GAS / clang, not 100% sure if Keil's ARMASM also uses that, and/or if it also allows `//` comments

Answer (score 1):

The move instruction (MOV) takes two parameters: either two registers, or a register and an immediate value. Thus, `(MOV R0, #1, i = 1;)` is invalid. Also, you don't need semi-colon at the end of each instruction. A comment can be made with double forward slashes. So, try this:

```
MOV R0, #1 //i = 1;
```

You can learn more from the ARM Compiler toolchain Assembler Reference, and/or watching some tutorials on YT such as [ARM instructions tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJHA0930mLc&list=PLN5_vOAFBsJtNWkbHzVYZ972B8E8GSNG1&index=16), or [sample loop program in assembly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jewXCm4-BX8&list=PLN5_vOAFBsJtNWkbHzVYZ972B8E8GSNG1&index=18)

Good luck!